# Testing async componentDidMount that calls setState, with jest/enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

i have the following code inside my `async componentdidmount`:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        let responseText = await API.Licensing()
        this.setState({ html: responseText })
    } catch (e) {
        this.setState({ html: 'Error Fetching Licensing Info' })
    }
}
```

i've been confused as to how to test the setstate here, since most examples from the internet uses promises then/catch while this one uses try/catch async/await.

how would the test look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import {
    shallow
} from "enzyme";
import axios from "axios";
import App from "./App";

jest.mock("axios");

it("fetches html", done => {
    const responseText = 'some text';
    axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(responseText);
    const wrapper = shallow( < App / > );

    setImmediate(() => {
        expect(wrapper.state().html).toBe('some text');
        done();
    });
});

it("transmits a useful message when fetching is not successful", done => {
    axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(new Error('error')))

    const wrapper = shallow( < App / > );

    setImmediate(() => {
        expect(wrapper.state().html).toBe("error");
        done();
    });
});
```

I suppose you can substitute *axios* with *API* above. You need to try it yourself. Something like:

```
import API from './API';

jest.mock("API");

... API.Licensing.mockResolvedValueOnce(responseText);
```

Another thing is that you might not need the *done* argument there, since the api responses are stubbed but better safe than sorry! Need to check this one too :) (I have to setup a project to check this out since I am curious...)

PS: For multiple promises you just need to stub the api responses changing *mockResolvedValueOnce* accordingly to whatever you need. Check here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html

Explanation: you mock your API response and shallow your component. Then you need to do all your checks inside the setImmediate function. To be honest it does not matter where you put this function. If you are curious try putting it on top of the test block. It is always executed at the end after all promises and callbacks have resolved. Alternatively, you can use process.nextTick or setTimeout with 0 time parameter. You can find out more in the nodeJS docs here: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Basically, you take advantage of the different queues of the JS event loop, timers callbacks etc

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained your code. :)

Comment: Is it better @Markus

Answer (score 0):

It may look something like this

```
test('Sets html to state', async () => {
    // Mock your api here...

    // using enzyme
    const component = await shallow(<YourComponent/>)

    // Waiting for all the promises in `componentDidMount` to resolve
    // max `i` may vary, it depends on the number of 'awaits' in  your code
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      await component.update()
    }

    expect(component.state('html')).toBe('someHtml')
})
```